# Desktop application with .net, angular and electron

Tags: c#, .net, angular, .net-core, electron

I am trying to create an electron desktop app with angular as frontend and .net as backend.
I created a sample angular project in .netcore 2.0 from VS 2017 and followed the steps mentioned [here](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET)

I'm having issues with `dotnet electronize init` command. It's giving below error :

```
No executable found matching command "dotnet-electronize"
```

Can someone please let me know if I'm missing anything.
Also if there is any boilerplate code which I can refer to would be really helpful.

Comment: Would you use `dotnet restore` and check it out this issue: https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/28

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was using powershell which seems to have some issues.

Comment: 0

was anyone able to get the desktop application with .net, angular and electron working? I was able to create a demo app with .net core, angular and electron but that is not what I want as I have certain libraries written in c# using .net framework and not core so certain classes like DNSEndpoint does not exists in .net core which I used in .net. Would appreciate if someone could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was using powershell which has some unexpected behavior.Check [here](https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET/issues/28) for more details.

Comment: bro, were you able to run electron with dot core as backend and angular as frontend?

Comment: @Dronacharya, yes. https://github.com/ElectronNET/Electron.NET will help you set it up.

Comment: Yeah. I followed it but couldn't accomplish the goal. Do you have the starter for DotNet Core and Angular with Electron?

Comment: i looked for it bro, couldn't find it :(

Answer (score 2):

Angular SPA with Dotnet Core and ElectronNet API

1. Open VS 2017 with Administrator mode
2. Create Asp.Net core Web Application with Angular template
3. Install the ElectronNET.CLI using following command "dotnet tool install ElectronNET.CLI -g"
4. Goto project folder and open cmd
5. Execute the following command "electronize init", it will create electron-manifest.json file in project folder
6. Right click on dependencies, goto Nuget package manager and install ElectronNET.API
7. Add ElectronBootstrap() method in Startup.cs

   ```
     public async void ElectronBootstrap()
     {
     BrowserWindowOptions options = new BrowserWindowOptions
     {
         Show = false
     };
     BrowserWindow mainWindow = await Electron.WindowManager.CreateWindowAsync();
     mainWindow.OnReadyToShow += () =>
     {
         mainWindow.Show();
     };
     mainWindow.SetTitle("App Name here");

     MenuItem[] menu = new MenuItem[]
     {
         new MenuItem
         {
             Label = "File",
             Submenu=new MenuItem[]
             {
                 new MenuItem
                 {
                     Label ="Exit",
                     Click =()=>{Electron.App.Exit();}
                 }
             }
         },
         new MenuItem
         {
             Label = "Info",
             Click = async ()=>
             {
                 await Electron.Dialog.ShowMessageBoxAsync("Welcome to App");
             }
         }
     };

     Electron.Menu.SetApplicationMenu(menu);
     }
   ```
8. Call that method from Configure() in Startup.cs

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
   {
   ...
   ElectronBootstrap();
   }
9. Add UseElectron(args) in Program.cs

   public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args)
   {
   return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
   .UseStartup()
   .UseElectron(args);
   }
10. Build the project
11. Goto project folder, open cmd and execute the following command "electronize start", it will open the desktop application. First time it will take time.
12. Production build for windows: electronize build /target win

Got it from here: https://github.com/rajeshsuramalla/AngularWithDotNetCoreElectronNET

Comment: Hi all, Does it work for Asp.net core with react instead of angular? if it is possible share any reference.